# How do I get values from all of these nodes?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

```
                Set<String> companies = companiesFile.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("companies").getKeys(false);

                sender.sendMessage("§2List of companies:");

                for (String s : companies)
                {
                    sender.sendMessage("§2" + companiesFile.getConfig().getString(s + ".name"));
                }
```

Above is the code I have so far.  I am coding a bukkit plugin and i am trying to figure out how to get the value "name" from all of the companies.  Do you know how to get the value "name" from all the companies?  Here is the config:

```
    companies:
      simpleco:
        expenses: 3000
        revenue: 6000
        name: SimpleCo
      projectempireco:
        expenses: 5000
        revenue: 5500
        name: ProjectEmpireCo
```

Comment: `getValues`should work https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getValues(boolean)

Comment: @Bajal How do you use the getValues() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the actual name value of each company you could first get all direct children keys in the `companies` section (like you've already done) so that if you later add more top level sections to your config file you won't have to traverse those.

If you are certain that every company will have a name value assigned to it, you can then simply either use the direct path (now that we have the name of each company section) with something along the lines of `companies.get(key + ".name")`, where `key` is the name of the company section (for example `simpleco`) and companies is the `ConfigurationSection` for all the companies or you could create a new `ConfigurationSection` one level deeper (one for each company) and retrieve the value for the key `"name"` by calling `getValues(false).get("name")` on that specific section. It would look something like this:

```
// Get config file, here called "fileConfig"
ConfigurationSection companies = fileConfig.getConfigurationSection("companies"); // The "companies" section of the config file

for (String companyKey : companies.getKeys(false)) { // For each company key in the set
    String name = (String) companies.get(companyKey + ".name"); // Either use the path to retrieve name value

    // OR

    ConfigurationSection companySection = companies.getConfigurationSection(companyKey); // Create a new section one level deeper
    name = (String) companySection.getValues(false).get("name"); // Retrieve name by getting value of key named "name"
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If the answer solved your problem, could you mark it as being the "accepted" answer using the checkmark? That way everyone knows your issue has been resolved. Thanks!